# Unable to get the text input outside of the loop accessing room Database

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to get the text from table in a roomDatabase, I access it by looping, and I use a foreach loop to access each item in the database

it manage work if I access the stringbuilder object inside the loop

```
var text = StringBuilder()
 db.adblogDao().getADBlog().forEach {

                it.forEach {
                    text.append("${it.log}")
                    text.append('\n')
                    // This work, why??
                  Timber.d("SUNLIGHT: ${text}")
                }
   }
   //text is always empty, why???
   Timber.d("MOONLIGHT: ${text}")
```

I want to access the string outside of the loop, but it always return null, why?

Answer (score 0):

Which one of MOONLIGHT and SUNLIGHT are logged first? When forEach is called by a worker thread, MOONLIGHT may be performed first, and then forEach may be performed.

Comment: How can I get Moonlight to log after SUNLIGHT is log?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think my answer is wrong. As far as I execute similar code, I think there is no problem.

Have you ever overwritten the variable name 'text' somewhere? Is it the same as changing the variable name of 'text' and executing it?

Comment: db.adblogDao().getADBlog().forEach {

            it.forEach {
                text.appendln("${it.log}")


                // Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                // code goes here
//                        binding.tvlog.text =  text.toString()

                // }
                // binding.tvlog.setText("${text}")
            }

//            binding.tvlog.text = text.toString()
        }
        Timber.d("MOONLIGHT: ${text}")

Comment: I think that it is my mistake that the thread to be executed is different.
If you change 'var text' to a unique name such as 'var testText', will the result change?
Also, if you change 'db.adblogDao (). GetADBlog ()' to 'list' as shown in the second answer, is MOONLIGHT empty also?

Answer (score 0):

my code:

```
class MyLog(val log: String)

val log1 = arrayOf(MyLog("1"), MyLog("2"), MyLog("3"), MyLog("4"), MyLog("5"))
val log2 = arrayOf(MyLog("10"), MyLog("20"), MyLog("30"), MyLog("40"), MyLog("50"))
val log3 = arrayOf(MyLog("100"), MyLog("200"), MyLog("300"), MyLog("400"), MyLog("500"))
val list = arrayOf(log1, log2, log3)

val text = StringBuilder()
list.forEach {
    it.forEach {
        text.append("${it.log}")
        text.append('\n')
        Log.d(TAG,"SUNLIGHT: ${text}")
    }
}
Log.d(TAG,"MOONLIGHT: ${text}")
```